# Updating a column(Null value to integer)

Tags: oracle

SO what I am trying to do is update a couple columns in one of my tables in sql. I need to update a value that is currently null to a value that is 0.75. I have done some research but I can't specifically find an answer related to my issue. Can anyone help me out? I know that it would read something like this if the value was not null,

```
UPDATE copy_f_staffs
SET overtime_rate='11.10'
WHERE id=12;
```

Comment: How does '11.10', a string, relate to the value 0.75?

Answer (score 1):

For oracle

```
  UPDATE copy_f_staffs
 SET overtime_rate='11.10'
  WHERE overtime_rate is null;
```

This will set your null overtime_rate fields to '11.10'

Comment: Awesome, thanks buddy. I'll mark as answer as soon as I can! :)